# Can't access localhost on a VM Windows Server 2012 Azure

Tags: apache, azure, windows-server

Hi I'm new to VM Technology. I have a Microsoft Bizspark Account with Azure on it. I created a Virtual Machine, Windows Server 2012 and installed Xampp on it. Yeah I know it would be better to use IIS but I want to use Xampp. I will use PHP. So basically I installed Xampp and the Web Server is Running. I tried to access the VM's localhost on other computer or my computer via Public IP of the VM and I can't access the VM's localhost. Am I doing it wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Questions on professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com).

Comment: Thank you Raf. I didn't know that there is a stackoverflow for servers/ vm's and networking. thanks for the link. :)